# Unexplained Android Intent Behaviour

Tags: java, android

im adding a camera scanning facility to a project of mine. Im using the following github https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo project

im attempting to call it from within an onclicklistener which is set within an adaptor i wrote

here is my onclicklistener

```
    imgCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           // Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanActivity.class);
          //  ((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);

            Intent intent =new Intent(context, ScanAdaptor.class);

        }
                                 }
```

i want it to call a class i wrote which uses startactivityforresult :

```
public class ScanAdaptor extends Activity {

    private Context context;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 99;

    String ba1;
    public String URL = "http:";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            int REQUEST_CODE = 99;
            int preference = ScanConstants.OPEN_CAMERA;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, preference);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

            context = this;


        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getExtras().getParcelable(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
               // scannedImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                upload(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] data) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    }


    private void upload(Bitmap bm) {
        // Image location URL
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        int flag = 0;


        ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, flag);

        Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

        // Upload image to server
        new uploadToServer().execute();

    }

public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {



    private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(((Activity) context));
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
        pd.show();
  }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        return "Success";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.hide();
        pd.dismiss();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(((Activity) context), MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("dir", "BS"); //Optional parameters
        ((Activity) context).startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
}
```

when this is the config nothing happens when you press the button.

its driving me mad, please help

Comment: What have you done debugging wise? Have you tried setting breakpoints to see where it is failing?

Comment: I had breakpoints all over the show. But it wasn't calling the scan adaptor for various reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClick` method doesn't launch the activity, it just creates the intent. Try this:

```
imgCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanAdaptor.class);
        ((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i had tried this however it still didnt work. Turns out i made a rookie error and not declared my activity in the manifest. This has resulted in some weird behaviour, which will have to wait until tomorrow. Thanks again